# Use all 10 digits to find the answer

Tags: mathematics

Use all 10 digits to find the answer (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
_ _ _+ _ _ _= _ _ _ _

Answer (score 3):

One solution is:

> 589+473=1062

But there are **A LOT** of answers (I've created this program before for an assignment - I don't remember how many, specifically).

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions with a different interpretation

> 67<sup>2</sup> + 10<sup>3</sup> = 5489
>  
>  56<sup>2</sup> + 17<sup>3</sup> = 8049